# Link created using javascript is not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I have created a more link using JavaScript. Its working fine in Firefox and crome.
But same is not working in IE.

Below is the code I have written for the same.

```
var underLine = document.createElement('u');
underLine.innerHTML = 'more';
var newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.setAttribute('class', 'a');
newlink.setAttribute('id', 'morelink'+count);
newlink.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'somejavascript');
newlink.appendChild(underLine);
someDiv.appendChild(newlink);
```

Can any one please help me out how to fix this issue for IE?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Remove the setAttribute statements, and check if the elements you're trying to add are actually added to the DOM. Use http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/ or something similar.

Comment: Also, try adding the 'href' attribute. Just setting it to '#' might be enough.

Comment: Element is there in DOM. Also I can see the same on my UI.

Comment: I have already tried the href attribute. Initially I had done like newlink.setAttribute('href', 'somejavascript');. But its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any content for the `<a>` element, do it like this:

```
newlink.innerHTML = 'click me';
```

Comment: `newlink.appendChild(underLine);`

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems a simple (ugly) work around:

Replace:

```
underLine.innerHTML = 'more';
```

With:

```
if(document.all)
    underLine.innerText = 'more';
else
    underLine.textContent = 'more';
```

Or:

```
if(underLine.innerText)
    underLine.innerText = 'more';
else
    underLine.textContent = 'more';
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is difference between this both?

Comment: As you see both are marked stripped.. the if statement is for MSIE work around but due to IE9 you can alter it for second option you can read: http://clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent/